# ANTLR4 grammar not correctly matching escaped quotes in strings

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, ebnf

I'm trying to create a grammar for a language that uses double quotes for strings and allows escaping of quotes with a backslash. I'm using ANTLR4 for parsing the input.

I've defined the following rule for matching strings:

```
STRING:
    '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;
fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\'
        (   // The standard escaped character set such as tab, newline, etc.
            [btnfr"'\\]
            |
        |   // A Java style Unicode escape sequence
            UNICODE_ESC
        |   // Invalid escape
            .
        |   // Invalid escape at end of file
            EOF
        )
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   'u' (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT?)?)?)?
;
```

However, this rule doesn't seem to correctly match strings that contain escaped quotes at the end of string. For example, the string `"test \"string\" that works"` is parsed correctly but when my string is like `"test string that does \"not work\""` this rule does not work. It also works for \n and other escaped chars.

(I am expecting to see `"test string that "works""` as output)

I've tried modifying the rule to escape the backslash in the quote character, like this:

```
STRING:
    '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"' | ('\\' '"'))
fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\'
        (   // The standard escaped character set such as tab, newline, etc.
            [btnfr"'\\]
            |
        |   // A Java style Unicode escape sequence
            UNICODE_ESC
        |   // Invalid escape
            .
        |   // Invalid escape at end of file
            EOF
        )
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   'u' (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT?)?)?)?
;
    ;
```

But this still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? How can I modify my grammar to correctly match strings with escaped quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The `ESC_SEQ` does not 'unescape' the sequence. You match `\"` so that is what you get in the output.

See https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md for how you can rewrite/skip etc on the various tokens to fix it.

Comment: HINT: It is not possible to do in ANTLR alone, you need to fall-back to implement a code handler for various usecases... e.g. that \u1234 becomes a unicode char NEEDs you to tell it how it should be parsed:  'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT? { setText(Character.toString((char) Integer.parseInt(getText().substring(2), 16))); }

Comment: what do you mean by ESC_SEQ does not "unescape" the sequence ? Sory i couldn't understand it.

Comment: @OguzhanKose Very verbatim, you have a rule called ESC_SEQ which parses a '\' followed by other things, such as '\"', but it JUST parses it it does not interpret it to a meaning, thus '\"' in the INPUT is '\"' in the OUTPUT.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce that. All of the following 4 strings match just fine:

- `""`
- `"simple"`
- `"test \"string\" that works"`
- `"test string that does \"not work\""`

Testes with the grammar:

```
lexer grammar StringLexer;

STRING
    :   '"' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

SPACE
    : [ \t\r\n] -> skip
    ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\'
        (   // The standard escaped character set such as tab, newline, etc.
            [btnfr"'\\]
            |
        |   // A Java style Unicode escape sequence
            UNICODE_ESC
        |   // Invalid escape
            .
        |   // Invalid escape at end of file
            EOF
        )
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   'u' (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT (HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT?)?)?)?
    ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT
    :   [0-9a-fA-F]
    ;
```

and Java code:

```java
String source = "\"\" \"simple\" \"test \\\"string\\\" that works\" \"test string that does \\\"not work\\\"\"";
StringLexer lexer = new StringLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
    System.out.printf("%-20s '%s'%n",
            StringLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
            t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

which prints:

```
STRING               '""'
STRING               '"simple"'
STRING               '"test \"string\" that works"'
STRING               '"test string that does \"not work\""'
EOF                  '<EOF>'
```

Comment: when i try to parse it it takes escaped double quote as the end of string and starts another string from the original unescaped double quote. I cant understand why it works when it is not at the end of strinng. Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Update your question with a small class others can easily run that shows the problem.